# As a programmer to be, intall Windows 7 Home or Professional or Ultimate?

Tags: windows-7

I am going to study for computer science.
As a programmer to be, I am considering whether to intall Windows 7 Home or Professional or Ultimate. Can you provide some pros and cons of the three? Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't matter at all. Pick one.

Answer (score 2):

Why limit yourself to just one? More is always better, right?

Chances are, if you are going away to study this type of thing then you will be using more than one system on a regular basis. And you won't be limited to just Windows...

This is also depends if you are going to purchase the software, or not. Your school will more than likely have an MSDN subscription and offer "free" software to you. I would personally wait to see what they offer and to also see what your classes require.